# issue with using innerHTML() and inserting javascript variable values into HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a small word counter for a school assessment and can't see what is wrong with this code. The idea is when you hit the submit button, it displays "Word Count: " and the amount of character put into a text box. I have showed the teacher my code and he agrees that he doesn't see a problem with it.

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var input = document.getElementById(userInput).value;
  if(submit.onclick) {
    document.getElementById("wordCount").innerHTML = "Word Count: " + input.length;
  };
};
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    </head>
      <body>
        <h1 style='font-family:verdana;text-decoration:underline;'>Word Counter</h1>
        <p>Please input text into the text box below:</p>
        <input type='text' id='userInput'/>
        <button id='submit'>Submit</button>
        <p id='wordCount'></p>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the issue that you are seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('#submit').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 const input = document.querySelector('#userInput');
  const inputValue = input.value;
  const wordsArray = inputValue.split(' ');
  document.querySelector('#wordCount').innerText = `Word Count: ${wordsArray.length}`;
})
```

```html
<h1 style='font-family:verdana;text-decoration:underline;'>Word Counter</h1>
<p>Please input text into the text box below:</p>
<input type='text' id='userInput'/>
<button id='submit'>Submit</button>
<p id='wordCount'></p>
```

First on window load there is likely no information inside the `#userInput`, meaning
`var input = document.getElementById(userInput).value;` will be undefined or `''`.

Second, you have no click event bound to your submit button so 
`submit.onclick` will return `false`;
[Binding DOM events](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp)

Lastly I switched from using `.innerHTML` to `.innerText` as there is no HTML being added into it. Also you your original code was not getting the word count, but would have returned the character count of the input text. To get word count I split the input text on spaces and returned the length of that array as the word count.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Much appreciated

Comment: @Jake no problem. If you could mark as answered that would be great for people coming later to this question.

Comment: It would be better to put the example in a stack snippet rather than jsfiddle.

Comment: @Barmar I honestly find it easier not too, but I will so the whole thing is hosted here.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting quotes around your `userInput` inside your `getElementById`. Right now you're trying to get an element by an ID of undefined because the userInput variable doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you, that was something i probably should of noticed earlier. Unfornutately, the code is still not working.